# Increase in db connections is slowing down query

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-rds

I have increase the number of replicas in kubernetes from 6 to 12. This also increase my db connections. I have noticed since then my queries are being impacted. I had one of the queries taking around 6 mins now the same query is taking 10 mins. The data is same and query is also same.

What can be the potential reason for this?

Comment: If your application performance is limited by database I/O, running more copies of the application will result in pretty much the behavior you're seeing: you have twice as many database requests but the same database capacity, so on average each request will take twice as long.

Comment: Everything is a trade off. Each connection has a certain cost in available resources and the request each makes. With 6 connections your server was essentially servicing 1 connection per minute. Now there may have been sufficient resources to absorb a couple extra connections but not to double them.   Solution: more resources, i.e. more memory and/or faster i/o devices.